# insert NULL values in tarantool using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, msgpack, tarantool

i'm having troubles with storing data in tarantool. In documentation stated that tarantool uses msgpack Data Types(https://tarantool.io/doc/1.7/book/box/data_model.html#data-types) . Msgpack has NULL, however python does not have NULL, also it seems like msgpack-python doesn't have it also. So how do i pass a NULL in that case? Also if in schema specified string type and i will try to pass NULL, there will be error? Thanks for the help and ideas beforehand!

Answer (score 1):

Python connector should be use native Python types, in this case — `None`. Also for Ruby and Crystal I can pass `nil` and Tarantool is working fine. In the [Python connector code](https://tarantool-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/module-tarantool.html?highlight=none#tarantool.Connection.select) I see that developers used type `None`. If you used `None` and got an error, then show you code?